# Datepicker component breaking an edit screen, using @unform and react-datepicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker, unform

I created the following component to select dates in UnForm:

```
export default function DatePickerInput({ name, ...rest }) {
  const datepickerRef = useRef(null);
  const { fieldName, defaultValue = '', registerField } = useField(name);

  const [date, setDate] = useState(defaultValue || null);
  useEffect(() => {
    registerField({
      name: fieldName,
      ref: datepickerRef.current,
      path: 'props.selected',
    });
  }, [fieldName, registerField]);

  return (
    <Label htmlFor={fieldName}>
      <UnInput>
        <ReactDatePicker
          ref={datepickerRef}
          selected={date}
          onChange={setDate}
          dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
          placeholderText="dd/mm/aaaa"
          writable="true"
          {...rest}
        />
      </UnInput>
    </Label>
  );
}
```

To save records the component is working normally, loading and saving the date I selected. When I am going to edit a record, when trying to load the date in the initial load, the page is broken and the following error is displayed:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot assign to read only property 'selected' of object '#<Object>'
```

If I comment out the line `path: 'props.selected'`, in `useEffect ()` the screen is not broken, but the date is not filled in the component. How do it work?

Comment: pls show more code. .. Uninput component, label component, usage of datepicker etc

Comment: @gdh https://gist.github.com/raphaelpradoo/aa301509820d78b726ff8ac258e750a1 https://gist.github.com/raphaelpradoo/ed20a035777a37bdc5d370f2fef699c9

Comment: Can you look at this?
https://unform.dev/examples/react-select
Try using getValue to see if that works.
Also can you log datepickerRef.current in useEffect to see what this objects has .
Maybe there's something on the state of DateComponent which can be set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue :**

`formRef.current.setFieldValue('birthday',value)` this will try to set value on provided `path` , in our case provided path is `props.selected`.

And `props.selected` is read-only property so you can't set value on `props` hence the error.

```
useEffect(() => {
    registerField({
      name: fieldName,
      ref: datepickerRef.current,
      path: 'props.selected', // <---- this is props, and it's readonly
      clearValue: (ref) => {
        ref.clear();
      },
    });
}, [fieldName, registerField]);
```

---

**Solution :**

You can remove the `path` and use `getter` and `setter` methods, named as `getValue` and `setValue` :

`setValue` : to set the initial value or whatever passed from `setFieldValue`

`getValue` :  to get value on submit

```
useEffect(() => {
    registerField({
      name: fieldName,
      ref: datepickerRef.current,
      clearValue: ref => {
        ref.clear();
      },
      setValue: (e, v) => {
        setDate(new Date(v)); // <---- Setting up default value 
      },
      getValue: () => {
        return datepickerRef.current.props.selected; // to get selected value from Date picker's props
        // OR
        return Date.toString(); // to get selected value from state it self
      }
    });
}, [fieldName, registerField]);
```

**WORKING DEMO** :

[image: Edit #SO-Datepicker-unform-setvalue]